Best way of installing outdoor outlet with conduit on outside only
I've searched the interwebs and found two general approaches to installing an outdoor outlet:

Find a nearby inside outlet. Poke a hole in the wall and extend a wire from that outlet. Put an outdoor box on top of the hole, run the wire through the back, and seal it up tight
Run conduit from the outdoor box, through the wall, all the way to either the panel or a junction box inside.

I want to do something between the two. I want to power the external outlet with power in that wall but the outdoor outlet needs to be a few feet away.
I was thinking about drilling a hole in the outside wall and sticking an LB conduit body in and sealing that tight. That would be the indoor/outdoor interface. Then running conduit from the LB to where the box goes. Then I can run THHN or UF-B from inside the wall to the outdoor box and receptacle.
Is that a legitimate strategy?

Are you planning to use conduit for the wiring on the inside of the house as well?

Another helpful bit of info might be your wall construction—concrete?  CMU?  Stick-built, with siding?  etc.

No conduit inside the house. It's stick-built with engineered wood siding. There's an existing inside outlet in the void (which is filled with insulation, but that's a different issue) that I want to use to source the juice. The issue is that I need the outdoor outlet a few feet away, so I want to seal the outside run from the point at which the wire exits the house to the outlet. The question I have is how best to transition from inside to outside.

It depends.
If I understand correctly, you want to use a conduit body near the back side of the existing interior outlet as a junction box, connecting to an outlet box several feet away.  You would need to run NM in the wall from your interior outlet to the conduit body (unless you can retrofit conduit inside the wall), and THHN/UFB in the conduit to your exterior outlet.  You'd need 10 cu in of box fill volume to splice the wires together if using #14 wire, and 11.3 CI if using #12.  For the typical LB PVC conduit body that you would use for this purpose, sufficient volume isn't provided til the 1" conduit size and larger.  So you'd need all the fittings to handle 1" conduit.
Or, you could just use the conduit body as a pull box, and run UFB only, all the way from the interior outlet, through the conduit, to the exterior outlet.  That's probably the easy button here, and you can basically get away with one size smaller conduit depending on your wire gauge.

Yes the "easy button" approach is what I was thinking. I never thought of using the LB as a junction box, although I now realize that's the only way to use THHN in the conduit since you can't use THHN inside the wall since it needs to be shielded to the inside box. What I was struggling with was a clean and compliant/safe way of transitioning from inside to outside.

I mean, you could use a standard exterior JB to transition, but a conduit body also works and may be a little more "low profile" than a standard JB.
